# How to get a value from a datatable using cypress?

Tags: cypress

[image]I want to get the 'Created On Date' from the datatable to find out which timezone it falls into?

I was searching for a particular campaign using filter. But I am not sure how to extract a text from the datatable.

```
    cy.get('input[placeholder="Filter..."]:nth(2)').type("campaign1");
    cy.get("tbody")
      .contains("campaign1")
      .closest("tr")
      .should("contain.text", this.Advertiser)
      .should("contain.text", this.Brand)
      .then(text => {
        const rowText = text;
      });
  }
```

But I got this response from Cypress

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: expected '<tr.MuiTableRow-root>' to contain text undefined, but the text was 'Advertiser UKBrand UKcampaign14 Nov 2019'
```

How do I extract just the date from the datable?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct way, but you're not searching deep enough. This should help:

```js
cy.get('input[placeholder="Filter..."]:nth(2)').type("campaign1");
cy.get("tbody")
  .contains("campaign1")
  .closest("tr")
  .should("contain.text", this.Advertiser)
  .should("contain.text", this.Brand)
  .find("td")
  .eq(5)
  .then(text => {
    const rowText = text;
  });
```

You did find the correct row, but not the correct cell. By adding the `find("td")` it does search for the cells. And the `.eq(5)` actually selects the 5th occurence of the `td`, which is the cell for the Created On column

Comment: Thanks J. But I still get the same error ```CypressError: Timed out retrying: expected '<tr.MuiTableRow-root>' to contain text undefined, but the text was 'Advertiser UKBrand UKcampaign14 Nov 2019'
```

Comment: It seems that Cypress never reaches the `then()` but already quites since a should failed. Could you try removing everything after `.should("contain.text", this.Advertiser)`. I bet your test will still fail. Cypress expects something to be 'undefined' and that is probably the value of `this.Advertiser`. You could also verify that by putting it in a log() like: `cy.log(this.Advertiser)`.

Comment: ```  cy.get("tbody")
      .contains("campaign1")
      .parent()
      .next("td")``` identified '4 Nov 2019', but how do I fetch the value and store it in a variable for future assertion

Comment: ```cy.get("tbody")
      .contains("campaign1")
      .parent()
      .next("td")
      .invoke("text")
      .as("txt");
    cy.log(this.txt);``` Returns empty value

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from your question is you just want to grab the date values and make an assertion on that.

Assumption Made: With filter applied you always get results and you want to write tests only for the cell with date.

**This might help you:**

```
function getTextOfCell(rowIndex){
  cy
  .get('tbody.MultiTableBody-root')
  .get('tr.MultiTableRow-root')
  .eq(rowIndex)
  .find('td').eq(3).invoke('text').then((txt)=>{
    cy.log(txt)
  })
}

describe('Test Test', ()=>{
  it('Test Test', ()=>{
    cy.visit('yourURl')
    cy.get('tbody.MultiTableBody-root tr.MultiTableRow-root').its('length').then((rowLength)=>{
      for(let i=0; i<rowLength; i++){
        getTextOfCell(i)
      }
    });
  })
})
```

**Note:**

- I am assuming that sometimes you will have more than one row as
  result. So iterating over all the available rows.
- And the date cell will have always have the index 3 for any
  row.
- In function `getTextOfCell` we are grabbing the text of the cell
  and saving it in `txt`. Here I am logging out only. You can
  make your assertion here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this.Advertiser` is undefined when the `should` function is called. You didn't provide the piece of code where this member is initialed, but I guess that it's initialed inside a `then` or it's a property. Anyway, like most Cypress methods, when `should` is called, it doesn't actually performs the validation, but only queues a command that will be executed later to perform the validation. This means that when `should` is called, `this.Advertiser` is still `undefined` and this gets passed as an argument to the`should` function, even though when the `should` *command is executed* later on, `this.Advertiser` has a valid value.

The solution should be, instead of using `this.Advertiser`, put the entire code block that appears in your question, inside the `then` block where the value in which `this.Advertiser` is initialized, and use the parameter passed to this `then` block instead. It should look something like this:

```
cy.somethingThatProvidesAdvertiser().then(advertiser => {
  cy.get('input[placeholder="Filter..."]:nth(2)').type("campaign1");
  cy.get("tbody")
    .contains("campaign1")
    .closest("tr")
    .should("contain.text", advertiser)
    .should("contain.text", this.Brand)
    .find("td")
    .eq(5)
    .then(text => {
      const rowText = text;
    });
  });
```

I guess that you should do the same for `this.Brand`, which means that you should have the 2 `then` clauses nested.

I hope I managed to explain it clear enough...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All for the responses. The below code helped me to fetch the desired value from the datatable.

```
const txt = [];
    cy.get("tbody")
      .contains("campaign1")
      .parent()
      .next("td")
      .invoke("text")
      .then(x => {
        txt.push(x);
      });
    cy.log((this.txt = txt));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you assign a cypress-dedicated id on a row/a column to easily extract data and tests are more maintainable.

```
<tr data-cy='campaign-${id}' ...>
  <td data-cy='created-on'>
   ....
  <td>
</tr>
```

For any given campaign, you can get its text with ease and code is readable.

```
cy.get('[data-cy=campain-3]').find('[data-cy=created-on]').invoke('text')
```